# iOS app localization: strange value in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, localization, xcode6, app-store-connect

We have an iOS app which does not have any localizations (it's English-only). In the past the builds had "English" in the "Localizations" field on the Build Details page in iTunes Connect. Yesterday though, I've noticed that that field shows the word "enc" instead of "English" (see screenshot). Is this a problem and how to fix it?

[image]

We have not changed any localizations in the project before this happened. We did however add iPad support and a new storyboard.

Below are the relevant settings in our project.

Storyboard settings:

[image: Storyboard settings]

Project settings:

[image: Project settings]

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved it? It looks like ITC bug...

Comment: I have the same issue for a test flight app and one in the app store.

Comment: @acrilige, no I haven't solved it. I haven't uploaded any new builds because I don't know what else I can do in my project with regards to localization.

Comment: Same problem here. It shows "... Spanish, enc, fuj"